# Noam Elimelech and the primary aspect of a mitzvah

Tags: sources-mekorot, commentaries, vayera, noam-elimelech

In [this article](https://aish.com/48937352/) By Rabbi Abba Wagensberg, a teaching from the Noam Elimelech is cited. It reads:

> The primary aspect of a mitzvah is not its technicalities and details, but rather the love we put into its performance. This does not mean to say that we should disregard the technicalities; on the contrary, we must perform them accurately and to the best of our ability. Nevertheless, when G-d weighs the two components of a mitzvah, He considers the love we put into its performance to be greater than even the act itself.

I have searched through his commentary on parshas Vayeira, but could not find it.

Does anyone know where the Noam Elimelech teaches us this and if this are his exact words?

Comment: Thanks for always bringing such thoughtful interesting questions! The exact wording he used is clearly very important, hatzlacha finding it.

Comment: Thanks. I once heard a Rabbi that I follow on YT, say that you must also look in the sources if a certain statement is true. You can say "the Noam Elimelech said such and so", but some people unfortunately try to bend the words into their favor. So that's why I like to aks these kind of questions. And also, I am a "bookie-guy" :)

Comment: The quote above sounds rather dangerous. This Noam Elimelech (https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%9D_%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9A/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%AA_%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%97) - דעיקר הלימוד התורה והמצוה הוא כדי להשיג עבודת השם באמת ביראה ואהבה שלימה בלי שום סיג ופסולת- says that the *purpose* of *mitzvos* is to achieve service of Hashem with fear and love, not that the primary aspect of *mitzvah* observance is the love put into the *mitzvah*.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE thanks. That is why I was wondering if this quote was the true essence of what the Noam Elimelech wrote. And I doubt that the Noam Elimelech speaks against himself in writing two opposite explanations on the essence of doing mitzvos, right? However, the last sentence of the quote above, seems not to be dangerous to me. Maybe it is just the author's own interpretation of that Noam Elimelech?!